# xxhdpi graphics takes too much space

Tags: android, android-drawable

I do not have too much icons but when I include `xxhdpi` versions of my icons it just took about 400kb of data which is too much I think.

I try too much to decrease the size of the APK but just a version of the icons took 400kb.

On the other hand, most of the apps from Google do not include xxhdpi assets. 
And when I do not include `xxhdpi` assets, the app does not look bad at all in my Nexus 5.

What do you think about it? Is it really logical to include `xxhdpi` graphics?

Comment: I think xxhdpi are mainly used with tablets. If your app runs mainly on phones and you have no special handling for tablets, you can drop it.

Comment: @M.Sameer Some of the most popular phones are xxhdpi... Nexus 5, Galaxy S4, HTC One. I would keep them if I were you, the next gen phones will be out soon which will have higher res screens!

Comment: @M.Sameer actually even the Nexus 10 table is xhdpi, xxhdpi means that lots of resolution in a small screen. I don't think there is a xxhdpi tablet at all.

Comment: @mario you are right but this is so much space for me. I have read a blog post that does lots of coding and effort just to reduce a small amount of APK size.

Comment: My only suggestion is... use a png optimizer, as OptiPNG: [http://optipng.sourceforge.net/](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decompiled the newest Google I/O 2014 application using `apktool` and I found that most of the graphic assets are only present in `xxhdpi` folder.

Instead of presenting 4 copies of images they only provided the biggest ones.

I think we will all do this in the future.